# Item in Active Record that gets created by default on rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake

Or something along those lines.  Say I have a belongs_to relationship, I want to have this belongs_to relationship to always default to an 'unknown entity' type of item.  This will make reporting on which items don't belong to anything very easy, and I won't have to force creation of the entity that it belongs to on creation of an item, things like that.  What would be the best way to do this?  I want the item to be automatically created when the database is created or when migrations are run.  Can this be put into a migration somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the sidebar as a related question.

I would use the db:seed option, which would then execute anything in the seeds.rb file.  More info can be found here for anyone with a similar question.

http://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/rake-db-seed-in-rails/